# How to use mongodb with javascript web application

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i am very much confused ...i need to use mongo db for databases in my web application..or simply i want to use mongodb for storing my web application data...i have searched but not getting the clear answer.

Answer (score 7):

MongoDB is a database, whereas JavaScript is a browser scripting language. The two shouldn't ever directly communicate (unless you're talking about NodeJS??). You should be sending information from JavaScript to your web server which will write/read/update/delete records in MongoDB. In turn, the web server should return data to JavaScript containing information about the result of the original request.

If you're asking this kind of question, you should read up more on how MongoDB works with a scripting language of your choice. You should also read up on JavaScript in general and how to communicate with a web server (try using [jquery](http://jquery.com/)'s ajax method).

Comment: Just a note, not all databases work this way. CouchDB is directly query-able from the browser since it provides a REST API.

Answer (score 1):

There are some resources online such as this talk 
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf-2011/building-web-applications-mongodb-introduction
which will give you some information on building web applications with mongodb - but maybe what you are looking for is a "building your first web application" tutorial as well to get you started?

Answer (score 1):

End-to-End JavaScript!

These are the best starters I could find on this subject:

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js

http://hectorcorrea.com/#/blog/introduction-to-node-js/51

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and